# How to use wildcard when appending PDFs using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, pdf

I'm working on a script that (as written) produces a large number of individual pdf pages (>100), instead of hardcoding the names of each of the outputs, I was thinking of using a wildcard. However, neither of the following seem to work:

```
 pdfDoc.appendPages("C:\\temp\\*.pdf")
```

or

```
 pdfDoc.appendPages("C:\\temp\\"*".pdf")
```

Below is the full script:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\temp\\Graffiti_DM3.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
graffitilyr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)[0]

newquery = '"Incident_Z" =' + "'10003'"
graffitilyr.definitionQuery=newquery
features = arcpy.SearchCursor(graffitilyr)
count = 1


for feature in features:
        df.rotation = "0"
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(graffitilyr, "NEW_SELECTION", "FID=" + str(count))
        #df.extent = graffitilyr.getSelectedExtent(True)
        df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
        df.scale = df.scale * .001
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        df.panToExtent(graffitilyr.getSelectedExtent())
        #df.scale = "1000"
        outpdf="C:\\temp\\" + str(count) + ".pdf"
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,outpdf)
        count = count+1

pdfpath="C:\\temp\\pdfbook.pdf"
pdfDoc = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(pdfpath)
for pdf in pdfs: 
        pdfDoc.appendPages("C:\\temp\\*.pdf")
pdfDoc.saveAndClose()
del features
del pdfDoc
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It seems that there are a couple of issues with your code.  I know that you've gotten assistance from a few people who gave you code samples to work with.  Your challenge now is getting them to fit together properly, and that is where you are having issues.  As I recall, you are trying to create individual pdf's of each exported area, correct?  If this is the case, then the logic for creating the pdf's needs to be inside the `for` loop.  Right now, the `pdfpath` variable and logic is just sitting out there not connected to anything.  You need to tie the script together.

Comment: With the last section of code, are you trying to add all of the pdf's you just exported, into one large pdf document?  If this is the case, then you need to define the `pdfs` variable.  Right now, you are referencing it, but it is empty.  It should be fed from a listing of pdf's in the directory you are saving them to.  Then you could step through each one and append it to the `pdfbook.pdf` document.  For example, this function, changed to look for pdf's would be helpful in your case:  [ListFiles](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ListFiles/018v0000000v000000/)

Comment: Great suggestions! I'm trying to add all of the pdfs exported into one large document. I was going to define the pdfs variable as a searchcursor, but I didn't think it was possible to use a search cursor outside of ArcGIS. Is it?

Comment: Not sure re the searchcursor.  If you are using an IDE and referencing the arcpy module, you should be able to use all the functions.  The function that I listed would probably work better than a searchcursor in this instance.  Also, there are specific python functions for working with the filesystem.  Look at, and search the python code repository:  [www.python.org](http://www.python.org)

Comment: FYI a search cursor in Arc context works only on a feature class or a table. You cannot just apply a search cursor to a variable(s); you would use a list of in that case, as the answer below! There do exist 'cursors' in other languages, usually formed with queries against data. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the 'for feat in feats' loop, after you create a pdf - add that path to a list.

ie

```
pdfList=[]

for feat in feats:
  arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,outpdf)
  count = count+1
  pdfList.append(outpdf)
```

Then use the list to append the pdfs together into one!

..

```
for aPdf in pdfList:
  pdfDoc.appendPages(aPdf)

pdfDoc.saveAndClose()
```

You were close, as @GetSpatial alluded, you just didn't populate your list.